# ORA-00905: missing keyword on ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this SQL request, works fine in PostgreSQL, but throws an error "Java::JavaSql::SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00905: missing keyword" in Oracle SQL. I assume, something here is an Oracle keyword, but can't find it. Tried changing "max" and "master" - same error.

```
  SELECT
    id AS "ID",
    imitation_mode AS "IMITATION_MODE",
    time_begin AS "TIME_BEGIN",
    time_end AS "TIME_END",
    max(time_begin) AS "MAX_TIME_BEGIN"
  FROM ssp_car_flow_master_plan master
  INNER JOIN (SELECT max(time_begin) FROM ssp_car_flow_master_plan) AS max
  ON master.time_begin = max
  GROUP BY imitation_mode, time_begin, time_end, id
```

Comment: `max` is the subquery alias, not a column

Comment: Remove `AS` before max. However, you need to name the column too.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `MAX` analytic function to avoid querying the table twice:

```sql
SELECT id,
       imitation_mode,
       time_begin,
       time_end
FROM   (
  SELECT id,
         imitation_mode,
         time_begin,
         time_end,
         MAX(time_begin) OVER () AS max_time_begin
  FROM   ssp_car_flow_master_plan
)
WHERE time_begin = max_time_begin;
```

Or, from Oracle 12, you can use `FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES`:

```sql
SELECT id,
       imitation_mode,
       time_begin,
       time_end,
FROM   ssp_car_flow_master_plan
ORDER BY time_begin DESC
FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES;
```

---

Your query fails because:

- In Oracle it is invalid syntax to use `AS` before a table/sub-query alias.
- `MAX` is a keyword and can be confusing if you use it as an alias.

If you want to fix your query then:

```sql
SELECT s.id,
       s.imitation_mode,
       s.time_begin,
       s.time_end,
       m.max_time_begin
  FROM ssp_car_flow_master_plan s
       INNER JOIN (
         SELECT max(time_begin) AS max_time_begin
         FROM   ssp_car_flow_master_plan
       ) m
       ON s.time_begin = m.max_time_begin
```

Comment: Isn't `MAX` a _non-reserved_ keyword? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_reserved_words

Comment: @jarlh It is listed in a table of reserved words in the [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/em.102/b40103/app_oracle_reserved_words.htm).

Comment: Strange, there are different lists... https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Oracle-SQL-Reserved-Words.html#GUID-55C49D1E-BE08-4C50-A9DD-8593EB925612

Comment: However, no problem to use max as identifier in regular Oracle SQL, https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=e031f8f5d1a6a76d46c7f2775b4ea5f1

Comment: @jarlh Yes, I was just finding that too... it probably is a keyword (and not a reserved word) in later versions but its still worth avoiding as an identifier as it has the potential to be confusing.

Comment: I agree, I would avoid it myself.

Answer (score 0):

Try and void using keywords as aliases. Your query logic seems slightly odd; youseem to want only the distinct records whose time_begin is equal to the latest time_begin in the table?

```
  SELECT DISTINCT
    master.id AS "ID",
    master.imitation_mode AS "IMITATION_MODE",
    master.time_begin AS "TIME_BEGIN",
    master.time_end AS "TIME_END",
    master.time_begin AS "MAX_TIME_BEGIN"
  FROM ssp_car_flow_master_plan master
  WHERE master.time_begin = (SELECT max(time_begin) FROM ssp_car_flow_master_plan)
```

To fix the query as presented:

```
  SELECT
    master.id AS "ID",
    master.imitation_mode AS "IMITATION_MODE",
    master.time_begin AS "TIME_BEGIN",
    master.time_end AS "TIME_END",
    max(master.time_begin) AS "MAX_TIME_BEGIN"
  FROM ssp_car_flow_master_plan master
  INNER JOIN (SELECT max(time_begin) AS mt FROM ssp_car_flow_master_plan) maxtime
  ON master.time_begin = maxtime.mt
  GROUP BY imitation_mode, time_begin, time_end, id
```

but as noted, it's a bit of a nonsense to inner join to a single value, then group everything else and aggregate the thing that can only be a single value